# resample on certain days in month using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a date column, and I want to resample this DataFrame in certain ranges (semi periodic).

For example
Here's the DataFrame:

```
Date
2012-01-19    130.0
2011-03-03    120.0
2011-05-05    105.0
2011-06-06    175.0
2011-06-06    200.0
2011-07-07    102.0
2011-08-08    300.0
2011-09-09    200.0
2011-11-11     10.0
2012-03-20     10.0
2011-12-12    130.0
2012-01-01     30.0
2012-02-02    150.0
2012-02-15    200.0
2012-03-15    120.0
2012-02-25     10.0
2012-01-29     90.0
```

I want to resample this in a semi-periodic way (date range is inclusive):

```
2011-01-01 
2011-01-02 - 2011-01-07 
2011-01-08 - 2011-01-15
2011-01-16 - 2011-01-22
2011-01-23 - 2011-01-28
2011-02-01 
2011-02-02 - 2011-02-07 
2011-02-08 - 2011-02-15 
2011-02-16 - 2011-02-22 
2011-02-23 - 2011-02-28
```

etc.

My current solution is as follows: using a "sticky date" and sum by groupby("StickyDate").sum():

```
def get_week_index_by_date(date):
    if date.day == 1:
        return 0
    if date.day < 8:
        return 1
    if date.day < 15:
        return 2
    if date.day < 22:
        return 3
    else:
        return 4


def get_sticky_date(date):
    return pandas.datetime(date.year, date.month, min(get_week_index_by_date(date)*7+1, 28))


df["StickyDate"] = df.Date.apply(get_sticky_date)
weekly_progress = df.groupby("StickyDate").sum()
```

Now I need to reindex so that missing dates are in my series as 0s and it's sorted by date:

```
def get_weekly_progress_index(start_date, end_date):
    curr_date = start_date
    while curr_date < end_date:
        for i in range(5):
            yield pandas.datetime(curr_date.year, curr_date.month, min(i*7+1, 28))
        curr_date += pandas.offsets.MonthBegin(1)

new_index = list(get_weekly_progress_index(weekly_progress.index.min(), weekly_progress.index.max()))

weekly_progress = weekly_progress.reindex(new_index).fillna(0)
```

My question - is there a more straightforward way of achieving this, or is this the best way to go about it?